# Add right-click functionality to a Windows 10 application

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-store

Certain Windows 10 applications (downloaded through the Microsoft Store) do not recognize any right-click input. I would like to configure an application to recognize right-clicks and to provide basic options (Copy, Paste, etc.) let me know if this is possible.

Comment: It's possible using a AutoHotKey script to supply a right-click context menu to applications that don't have any such menu. Some programming is required.

Comment: In addition to @harrymc , the controls need to be standard win32 controls and not owner drawn.  You might figure out if the keyboard copy paste work before worrying about the right-click menu.  This is a lot of work with very little reward.

Answer (score -1):

Unless the application is open-source and you or someone else modifies the code accordingly to the intended behavior then no, it's not possible.